# Is there any way to join Dictionary keys as string in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to join Dictionary keys as string without using loop.

Comment: No. Not without looping. That's like asking "how can I get from A to B" without moving A or B.

Answer (score 3):

```
string separator = ",";//Or whatever you want
string myKeys = string.Join(separator, yourDictionary.Keys);
```

Note: Still `string.Join` method will loop it internally though you don't see the loop.